# Change tooltip control

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, tooltip

I have a series of `textboxes` with which I want to associate a `tooltip` with. This `tooltip` would appear when the user clicks on a black `textbox`, then disappear when they start typing or when they leave the `textbox`. The `tooltip` should be placed directly above the `textbox`, this is why I'm using the `ToolTip.Show` method instead of the `ToolTip.SetTooltip` method (it lets me control the placement).

So far, for each `textbox` I have 3 methods; Enter, Leave and TextChanged:

```
tt = new ToolTip();
String message = "some message"; //different for each textbox

private void textbox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox1.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        tt.Show(message, textbox1, new Point(0, -2 * textbox1.Height));
    }
}

private void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tt.Hide(textbox1);
}

private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tt.Hide(textbox1);
}
```

Now consider two `textboxes`. Clicking on `textbox1` triggers the `tooltip` as expected, in the expected location, then exiting `textbox1` causes it to disappear. Trying the same thing on `textbox2` also works. Now if I click on `textbox1` again, the `tooltip` has the proper message, but the placement is in the same place as if I had clicked on `textbox2`. Not only that, but the shape of the `tooltip` is the same as for `textbox2`, meaning that my message gets truncated. (The message for `textbox1` is longer than the one for `textbox2`). Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Try to create two different object of tool-tip for two text-boxes. `ToolTip t1 = new ToolTip()` for `TextBox1` and `ToolTip t2 = new ToolTip()` for `TextBox2`

Comment: @asifsid88: Yes, that is one possible solution; but as I have around 20 textboxes I'd like to stick with just one toolTip. What I have above should work; at least as I understand toolTips.

Comment: you should create an Usercontrol with this functionality, and have the tooltip instance declared inside the usercontrol.

Comment: I have not used ToolTip before, so just saying (apologize if I'm wrong), isn't there any property in ToolTip to set X, Y (or precisely position) so everytime you do `tt.Show` you set it's X, Y and width such that it's position is moved or width is increased. Try to do with JS if you're comfortable

Comment: @asifsid88: You would think it would have a position property, but I can't find one. The `ToolTip.Show` method lets me set the position, but I don't think I can modify it after that.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new instance of the ToolTip control each time you use it? E.g.: tt = new ToolTip(); tt.Show(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens I think when the `IsBalloon` property is true.  Unfortunately, known bug.

Try it like this:

```
private void textbox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (textbox1.Text == String.Empty) {
    tt.Show(string.Empty, textbox1, 0);
    tt.Show(message, textbox1, new Point(0, -2 * textbox1.Height));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `IsBalloon` is set to `true`, by setting it to `false` the problem is solved. Is your solution supposed to work even if `IsBalloon` is set to `true`? Because I tried it, and I'm still having the same problems.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help, by the way. That seems like a rather obscure bug, safe to say I would never have figured that out on my own.

Comment: @HH Yes, this solution is for when the tooltip is using balloons.

Comment: Still having the same problems with balloon ToolTips. Do the other functions need to changed in any way?

Comment: @HH Not using balloons is probably the best solution since it's buggy.    For the most part it works.  I noticed if I tab fast through my textboxes the tip will show a black rectangle sometimes.  Never been a fan of the balloon tip though so I've avoided it.

Comment: OK, that sounds like the best bet then. I think aesthetically they're more pleasing; but it's not worth the risk of them bugging out.